# How to override remote git "commits ahead"

Tags: git

I have been trying to merge some git branches which I screwed up a bit. Anyway, I am now in a situation, where my most recent local commit represents the state I want recorded on the remote repo.

However, my local repo is 2 commits behind my remote repo. What is the best way to sync my local and remote repos, such that my local files don't chang at all?

Comment: `git push --force`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with a branch that no one else is using, then you can use

```
git push --force
```

Keep in mind that this is a very dangerous command, as you will not only wipe out some commits on that branch (including any that might have been introduced by colleagues without your knowledge) but you will also create a mess of a situation with any other branches that include those now missing commits.

A tamer version of `--force` is `--force-with-lease`, which will at least ensure that you don't overwrite commits that your local repo wasn't aware of.

You might want to consider using

```
git rebase --interactive <commit-hash>
```

where `<commit-hash>` is the last commit that you still have in common with your original branch. You can then squash all commits since that commit, then either merge in or rebase against your original branch then push to the server normally. This would be a less risky way to get your changes back to the server.

Comment: I had a similar problem but am using the SourceTree Mac Git client and found that the option to force push is not available by default, but can be enabled in SourceTree 4.0.2 at Preferences/Advanced "Allow force push" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

just start another branch from a given commit and begin workin on the new branch,

no need to rewrite history.